# Rails redirect_to not reloading edit with new instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, model, routes

On my `/edit` page I have a form #1 whose output `layer_2_inputs` is supposed to trigger the loading of form #2 in the view.

Here is my controller:

```
def edit
  if params[:layer_2_inputs].present?
    @layer_2_inputs = params[:layer_2_inputs]
  end
  # binding.pry => @layer_2_inputs => ['a','b','c'] 
end

def layer_1    
  # takes params from layer_1 form 
  layer_2_inputs = ['a','b','c']

  redirect_to edit_query_path(@query, layer_2_inputs: layer_2_inputs)
end
```

So binding.pry tells me that `@layer_2_inputs` are set, but `<%= @layer_2_inputs %>` renders nothing in the view when redirect_to reloads it! Strangely, the radio buttons for layer_1 form are still checked when I reload the page.

**Am I using `redirect_to` improperly?**

Here is the js that I am using to submit layer/ form 1

```
var formSubmit = function() {
  $('.layer_1_radio').change(function(){
    $('#layer_1').submit();
  });
};

$(document).ready(formSubmit);
```

Rails 5.0.1
ruby 2.3.0p0

Comment: You should be able to go to edit (without redirect) and pass in a param and see a rendered view.  Go to `/queries/1/edit.html?layer_2_inputs=yes`

Comment: Wow. My layer_2 block tries to run when I try your string. My get for edit is being processed as `/queries/3/edit?layer_2_inputs%5B%5D=Video` because `["Video"]` is the actual value I am passing.

Comment: And if I do `http://million.dev/queries/3/edit?layer_2_inputs%5B%5D=Video` then it works as intended! So why are the params getting dropped when I run redirect_to?

Comment: The redirect should put the param in the query string.  Is it something to do with the array?  Try a string for "layer_2_inputs"

Comment: Hmm `Started GET "/queries/3/edit?layer_2_inputs=yolostring"` still redirects as `/queries/3/edit`. Maybe it's because my edit route is defined by `resources :queries`?

Comment: @Swards I decided to rearchitect this to load the new values in partials using forms with `remote: true`. Thank you for the help!